# Loading a webpage from an application and then clicking a link on that page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I'm writing an app which should load a website. After the website is loaded, I have to fire up a 2nd command to the web page, which is kind of Javascript scriptlet.

I did this manually in my browser and in generally it seems to work fine.  They way I did it manually was I created two shortcuts in my browser:

1. the URL to this website (e.g. `http://www.example.net/123456-e.aspx`)
2. the shortcut to a Scriptlet which calls a function on this website (e.g. `javascript:__doPostBack('Video_Info1$Rating_control1$lnk_star5',''))`.

I first click the URL shortcut and after its loaded, I fire up the 2nd shortcut.

But how can I do this in a C# application?

---

But, what I'm trying to do is quite the opposite I think.

I'd like to SEND a `_postBack` to an existing site. 
I'm not writing my own site which contains a postBack control!

Let me explain a little in detail...

the site I'm loading in my app is an existing ASPX site in the web. 
In this site, you'll find several `_doPostback` entries and in a browser, the postBack event (when I hit it manually within a bookmark/shortcut) will be send back and has its desired result (in this case, its assigning "5 stars" to tell everybody, that something is supergood ;-).

So, what I'd like to do is to write my C# App which will send this `_postBack` command every time I hit the OK button or some other events. 
Just as it is with my link above

```
"javascript:__doPostBack('Video_Info1$Rating_control1$lnk_star5','')"
```

This is the bookmark I have on my browsers bookmark panel - a shortcut!

.... Just to be honest, its a kind of cheat, which will do an automatic voting on an external site...

My prob is now,... how can I send this `_postBack` straight to the site, to increase my stars?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, The code which you are seeing (`_doPastBack(..)`) is actually going to  invoke a server method (code in your codebehind of that page).

You can create a webpage and have an iframe and load your first page in that.The user will be able to click on any of the button and invoke the corresponding server code if there is one attached.

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.example.net/123456-e.aspx"></iframe>
</body>
```